# Incorrect binding for @OneToMany with multiple join columns in the latest spring data jpa version 3.0.2

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Following is my entity class where I am using @OneToMany annotation, which leads to incorrect binding. ref_no and seq_no are my binding parameters. But the binding values are out of order. Value for ref_no binds with seq_no and value for seq_no binds with ref_no.

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "REF_NO",referencedColumnName = "REF_NO"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_NO",referencedColumnName = "SEQ_NO")
    })
    public Set<InProcessPartyEntity> getParties() {
        return parties;
    }
```

Output trace log:

Hibernate: select p1_0.seq_no,p1_0.ref_no,p1_0.party_code,p1_0.party_id from rbi_trade.ot_txn_party p1_0 where (**p1_0.seq_no,p1_0.ref_no**) in((?,?))
2023-03-09T08:31:42.540+01:00 TRACE 15588 --- [   scheduling-1] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [**E313100005323221237**]
2023-03-09T08:31:42.540+01:00 TRACE 15588 --- [   scheduling-1] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [**001**]

In the same entity class I am also using @OneToOne annotation with multiple join columns, which works perfectly fine and leads to the correct binding parameters values

```
    @OneToOne(fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "REF_NO",referencedColumnName = "REF_NO"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_NO",referencedColumnName = "SEQ_NO")
    })
    public InProcessWorkUnitEntity getWorkUnit() {
        return workUnit;
    }
```

Output trace log:

Hibernate: select i1_0.ref_no,i1_0.seq_no,i1_0.reg_by from rbi_trade.ot_workunit i1_0 where (**i1_0.ref_no,i1_0.seq_no**) in((?,?))
2023-03-09T08:31:42.524+01:00 TRACE 15588 --- [   scheduling-1] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [**E313100005323221237**]
2023-03-09T08:31:42.525+01:00 TRACE 15588 --- [   scheduling-1] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [**001**]

I am facing this issue since I upgraded to spring boot jpa 3.0.2. I was using version 2.7.2 before where the binds with @OneToMany worked fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if the opposite `@ManyToOne` relation is defined on `InProcessPartyEntity`, try to transfer the `@JoinColum` on that relation and use `mappedBy` on the `@OneToMany`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't help my case. This seems to be a bug in the latest hibernate version. More details can be found here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16274

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issue is to remove @Id annotation from the Id class.
This issue will be fixed in a newer version of Hibernate ORM. i.e. if the entity is annoted with the @IdClass , the tag @Id from the ID class needs to be ignored.

More details can be found in the comments section of my post here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16274

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to leave a comment, so I'll write my considerations in an answer.

Is the relationship bidirectional? It would help if you could share the `InProcessPartyEntity` class code too. Actually, it would help a lot if you could share at least both entities properties and their mappings.

One thing I noticed when updating to JPA 3 was that Hibernate became stricter when validating annotations mapping.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have created a reproducer for this issue and reported it here . I have created a test case which runs fine with older version of hibernate and fails with the latest version. Links to the gitHub repositories can be found inside the ticket: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16274